# Strptime returning all rows of Pandas dataframe instead of just one row

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataset like this:

```
Policy | Customer | Employee | CoveredDate | LapseDate
123    | 1234     | 1234     | 2011-06-01  | 2013-01-01
124    | 1234     | 1234     | 2016-01-01  | 2013-01-01
124    | 5678     | 5555     | 2014-01-01  | 2013-01-01
```

I'm trying to iterate through each policy for each employee of each customer (a customer can have many employees, an employee can have multiple policies) and compare the covered date against the lapse date for a particular employee. If the covered date and lapse date are within 5 days, I'd like to add that policy to a results list.

So far, I've used this code:

```
import pandas
import datetime

wd = pandas.read_csv(<<FILE LOCATION>>)

Resultlist=[]
for Customer in wd.groupby(['Employee', 'Customer']):
    for Policy in wd.groupby(['Employee', 'Customer']):
        EffDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(wd['CoveredDate']),'%Y-%m-%d')
        for Policy in wd.groupby(['Employee', 'Customer']):
            lapsedate = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(wd['LapseDate']),'%Y-%m-%d') + datetime.timedelta(days=5)
            if effdate < LapseDate:
                Resultlist.append(wd['Policy','Customer'])
```

I end up getting an error where the strptime function is taking **every** row of my dataframe in as one input, instead of just focusing on the iteration it's currently on - so for my example above, I would get:

```
ValueError: time data '0    2011-06-01\n1    2016-01-01\n2    2014-01-01\nName:
```

CoverageEffDate, dtype: object' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

I'm not entirely sure why it's trying to pull in every object as I've followed the format of a few other answers on SE detailing how to iterate through a pandas dataframe - I'd greatly appreciate if someone can help me figure this out!

Comment: Can you share the expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you want all records where wd['LapseDate'] & wd['CoveredDate'] are within 5 days.

Use [pd.to_datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert to date time formats

```
wd['LapseDate'] = pd.to_datetime(wd.LapseDate)
wd['CoveredDate'] = pd.to_datetime(wd.CoveredDate)
wd['diff'] = ((wd['LapseDate']-wd['CoveredDate']).dt.days).abs()
print wd[(wd['diff']<366)] # change 365 to 5
```

Input

```
   Policy  Customer  Employee CoveredDate  LapseDate  diff
0     123      1234      1234  2011-06-01 2013-01-01   580
1     124      1234      1234  2016-01-01 2013-01-01  1095
2     124      5678      5555  2014-01-01 2013-01-01   365
```

output  - Here I filtered for diff less than 366, change that to 5

```
  Policy  Customer  Employee CoveredDate  LapseDate  diff
2     124      5678      5555  2014-01-01 2013-01-01   365
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps!

I should have expanded on my goal - I actually want to compare each covered date to every other lapse date for an employee number - so you would compare policies 123 and 124. If the difference between policy 123's Cover date and 124's lapse date was 5 days, then I want to add it to a list.

That said, the pd.to_datetime function is what I was looking for to resolve the error I had - thank you!!